# How to interpret the following C (includes bit fields and a struct)

Tags: c++, c, microcontroller, pic

The following code is from a PIC microcontroller header file, but I assume it's plain old C.
I understand that the code is to be used for accessing individual bits at an address in memory, but as a C novice, I'd like some help in understanding what is going on here, and how I'd go about using it in my code to set or get bits from ADCON1.

```
volatile unsigned char           ADCON1              @ 0x09F;

volatile bit VCFG0               @ ((unsigned)&ADCON1*8)+4;
volatile bit VCFG1               @ ((unsigned)&ADCON1*8)+5;
volatile bit ADFM                @ ((unsigned)&ADCON1*8)+7;

volatile union {
    struct {
        unsigned                        : 4;
        unsigned    VCFG0               : 1;
        unsigned    VCFG1               : 1;
        unsigned    : 1;
        unsigned    ADFM                : 1;
    };
} ADCON1bits @ 0x09F;
```

tagged to C and C++. Let me know if it's not C++ compatible code, and I'll remove the tag

Comment: The definition of `@` and `bit` is missing.

Comment: This is neither plain old C nor plain old C++. There's no `@` symbol in either (except in strings).  It is probably a vendor-specific thing. You need to consult the compiler's documentation. I guess it specifies the absolute address of the variable, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
volatile unsigned char ADCON1 @ 0x09F;
```

This simply declares the `ADCON1` variable. `volatile` means accesses should not be optimized out, because the variable contents may change during execution. (ie. the hardware updates the value.)

I'm guessing the `@` syntax is non-standard C; I've never seen it before. But I figure it means the value is to be found at offset `0x09F`.

```
volatile bit VCFG0 @ ((unsigned)&ADCON1*8)+4;
volatile bit VCFG1 @ ((unsigned)&ADCON1*8)+5;
volatile bit ADFM  @ ((unsigned)&ADCON1*8)+7;
```

These again declare variables. The `bit` type is also not standard C, as far as I know, but should be self-explanatory.

The `@` syntax is again used here to declare the location, but the interesting thing is that apparently the offset is in type-increments, because the address of `ADCON1` is multiplied by 8. (A `char` is 8 times the size of a `bit`.)

It's much the same as you'd index an array or do pointer arithmetic in regular C, for example: `char foo[4]` is an array 4 bytes in size, but `int bar[4]` is an array 32 bytes in size. Except in this case, your 'array' is the processor's entire address space.

So basically, these variables represent specific bits of `ADCON1`, by taking the char-address (`&ADCON1`), converting it to a bit-address (`*8`), then addressing the specific bit (`+4`).

```
volatile union {
    struct {
        unsigned          : 4;
        unsigned    VCFG0 : 1;
        unsigned    VCFG1 : 1;
        unsigned          : 1;
        unsigned    ADFM  : 1;
    };
} ADCON1bits @ 0x09F;
```

This declaration is independent from the above, but achieves about the same.

A union of one struct is declared, and a variable of that type is declared at offset `0x09F`. The `:4` syntax you see in the struct indicates a bit-size of the member. Nameless struct members are simply inaccessible.

The union doesn't seem to really add anything here. You'd access bits as `ADCON1bits.VCFG0`.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, especially the addressing of the bit fields being related to the type. It's a weird concept for me. The clarification that the two blocks of code are unrelated was a surprise, but makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, there is a byte register at 0x09F that controls the ADC, 'bit' is a boolean type that can be addressed as a bit array starting at 0, (hence the *8), so the ADC is accessed by, eg. 'ADFM=0'.

The union is an alternative means to access the ADC control register using bit fields, (eg. ADCON1bits.VCFG1=1).

The whole lot is not really standard C or C++ - it's 'microController C'

Comment: The bit array concept was the strangest to me. It sort of makes sense now, but regardless, I can now use it!